# What is difference between revoke session and account lock?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am not getting the difference between these 2 queries,

1.alter user username account lock;
2.REVOKE CREATE SESSION FROM username;

how these queries will affect user ?

If I use revoke session then what operations will be possible ?
And what will be possible if I use account lock ?

Comment: There is little practical difference, other than the privileges you need. The effect on the user is the same. [Tom Kyte has a written about this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:178078700346681923), of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `ALTER USER x ACCOUNT LOCK`

This has two benefits. For one, `REVOKE CREATE SESSION` does not guarantee that the user cannot connect to database ([surprise!](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:178078700346681923#5661055800346364798)). Secondly, in many places you can bet that one day audit comes and asks one of their favorite questions "when was this account locked?". With `REVOKE` you don't have this date at hand, you need to go and search through audit logs, with `LOCK` the answer sits right there in `DBA_USERS`.